# What is the Json response we should send to microsoft botFramework to route my response to telegram channel

Tags: botframework, telegram, telegram-bot

I am sending below response to the service url provided by botFramework request https://telegram.botframework.com/v3/conversations/-263387177/activities/

My intent is that using sendMessage method of telegram I am able to route a text to the telegram channel via microsoft botframework

The http post which I am sending is as below

```
  {
    "type": "message",
    "locale": "en-Us",
    "chat_id":-263387177,
    "channelID":"telegram", 
     "from": {
        "id": "GTSFIBot",
        "name": "sapeops"
    },

   "text":"hi , Greetings!",
   "replyToId": "1505813737353",
    "recipient": {
        "id": "DirectLineClient"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "isGroup": true,
        "id": "-263387177",
        "name": "sapeops group"
    },
    "channelData": {
        "method": "sendMessage",
        "parameters": {
             "chat_id": -263387177,
            "parse_mode": "HTML",
            "text": "<B>Greetings! How are you doing?</B>"

        },
            "chat": {
                "id": -263387177,
                "title": "sapeops group",
                "type": "group",
                "all_members_are_administrators": true
            }
    }

}
```

I get 502 bad gateway response and a below JSON.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ServiceError",
        "message": "Telegram API returned a result code indicating non-success"
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to send manually instead of using the Bot Framework implementation? Why?

Comment: I am using the rest api of Bot framework and Integration is working for Skype and Cortana , I have my implementation in Java. Want to see what is the REST message that is sent to the service url https://telegram.botframework.com/v3/conversations/-263387177/activities/